# Get suggestions in defined command via newcommand

Tags: overleaf

I'm using my own Overleaf instance and defined a command like this:

```
\newcommand{\reff}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{figure~\ref*{#1}#2}}
```

so I can reference a part of a figure with a letter.
However, since I am not using the usual \ref command, the figures that I would like to refere to are not suggested by the editor. Is there a way to get suggestions with a userdefined command?

Comment: If you look at the aux file for `\newlabel`, the last argument is the hyperref anchor.  They use a fairly rigorous naming protocol, so much so that `\autoref` relies on it.  Alternatively, you can use `\getrefbykeydefault{<label>}{anchor}{Doc-Start}` to get the hyperref anchor given the label name.